# Should a preview be added to an address form?

Tags: usability, input, addresses, preview

**Task**

The user wants to correct an address. The wrong address is displayed on the left and the user can enter or correct the address on the right in the address form.

[image]

**Edit: Context**

The addresses belong to rejected mail. In several different ways (phone, email etc.) the users figure out the correct address and enter it in the form. (I would rather not discuss this topic, I tried to simplify and focus the question.) They receive several of these tasks in their inbox each day and need to complete them the same day if possible.

**Situation**

The developers added a preview of the corrected address below the original address. On the one hand I see that provides a better overview than the input form. On the other hand it also causes more clutter and disrupts the input flow. Even if the preview is for example displayed above or below the save button I think there is a lot of redundancy.

**Question**

To add or not to add this feature?

Comment: This is an interesting question but you need to dig a bit deeper because in my opinion, right now  you are assuming that a user does not know his address by hearth and I assume in 90% of the cases that is not a good assumption.

Where in the timeline is the user prompted to correct the address ? Does he randomly figure out that he entered a bad address ? Or you tried to send a package to that address and found out that his address is bad, prompted him to correct it and this is where we are right now ? Or you require a specific format ? Please detail in order to get a good relevant answer.

Comment: _Or you tried to send a package to that address and found out that his address is bad, prompted him to correct it and this is where we are right now ?_

Comment: I wanted to actually write this: Thank you for your reaction. They do not need enter their own address, but an address they need to do a little research for. So it is rather this case: _.. you tried to send a package to that address and found out that his address is bad, prompted him to correct it and this is where we are right now ?_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a reasonable usecase for that kind of preview - and it's actually used on this very site: markup or special formatting/layouting. While I'm entering plain text in the textarea/form, I would like to preview what the actual answer is going to look like.

The same rationale could be applied to your scenario. We're constantly looking for recognizable patterns and subconsciously split content into [chunks](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/chunking/), because it helps us process the information.
Addresses are normally organized in a specific format (as seen on the undeliverable address in your screenshot). Whenever we see an address written like this, we immediately recognize it as an address, before we have even read the whole of it.

The form on the other hand breaks with this convention and therefore makes it harder to scan and check the entered information. Organizing the content in the well-known format makes it easier for users to process the information because they are already used to this form of representation. Therefore, providing a properly formatted preview would make it easier for users to check on the entered data and could prevent additional mistakes.

Another option is to reorganize your form fields to mimic the address format. In this case, I would argue that the preview isn't really necessary (while it could still be provided as an additional check, if desired). The Nielsen Norman Group has established some recommendations on how to design [website forms](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/web-form-design/) that could help you here.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see any benefits of showing a preview of the address to the user, especially if no feedback is provided on why the first address was wrong.

Please consider instead developing on form address validation that aids the user. 
( Is the format ok ? , zip code exists within the city and country ? , is overall street name length ok ? etc. )

There are also tools that offer address validations for correct completion where you can prompt users to either fix the address based on the suggestion given by the verification company or have them double check and confirm the address they have added is correct.

Please have a look here:
https://baymard.com/checkout-usability/benchmark/step-type/address-validator

Comment: I am aware of that and we are doing that where possible. The question is really about the benefit of the preview. I understand that you don't see it. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

The way I interpret your scenario, you mean that a user of your system has to correct addresses for several people (not themselves) who've had undelivered mail.

The only benefit the preview adds is a comparison to the wrong address in the same format. If that format, how it's printed on a letter / parcel is of importance, is important then I would say it is useful. If the format is not relevant than you could remove it and  show the wrong address in the format of the form, making it easier to compare.